# How to type & in acronym list on latex

Tags: acronyms

I am adding the following acronym :

```
\newacronym{D&IR}{D&IR}{Diagnostic and Interventional Radiology}\Gls{D&IR}
```

However I end up with **DIR** Diagnostic and Interventional Radiology. How can I include the '&' in the acronym list and on my text? I already tried to use the following:

```
\newacronym{D\&IR}{D\&IR}{Diagnostic and Interventional Radiology}\Gls{D\&IR}
```

However I got an error and the script did not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed for an acronym label to contain active characters like the ampersand. However, the actual acronym can contain this character. You do need to escape it in the acronym using `\&`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\newacronym{DIR}{D\&IR}{Diagnostic and Interventional Radiology}\Gls{DIR}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Reference from the `glossaries` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf), page 95 (original emphasis):

> For all the above commands, the first argument, *⟨label⟩*, must be a
> unique label with which to identify this entry. **This can’t contain any
> non-expandable commands or active characters.** The reason for this
> restriction is that the label is used to construct internal commands
> that store the associated information (similarly to commands like
> `\label`) and therefore must be able to expand to a valid control
> sequence name.